# CORS aiohttp, fetch js

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, json, fetch, aiohttp

у меня есть сервер на aiohttp, для поддержки CORS я использую сигнал

```
app.on_response_prepare(on_prepare)
async def on_prepare(request, response):
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
```

На клиенте следующее

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let options = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: myHeaders
    };
    console.log("Try to fetch");
    fetch("http://localhost:8000/login", options)
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((auth) => {
          console.log(auth);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {console.log("error -> " + err)});
```

Ошибка

> Failed to load http://localhost:8000/login: Response for preflight
>   does not have HTTP ok status.

До того, как я поставил сигнал, была ошибка кросдоменного запроса, сейчас ее вроде нет, но появилась та, которую я указал выше. В чем может быть дело ?

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно убрать все заголовки на клиенте.